# All pairs shortest path lengths in a large undirected weighted graph with cycles in Python

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path

I am looking for an working algorithm to find the shortest path lengths (only the lengths not the paths) from all nodes to all other nodes. The graphs have around 2000 - 4000 vertices and around 3,5 times more edges. The graph looks something like this: [A simple drawing of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlKx9.png)

I am working in Python and I've tried an implementation of the Floyd Warshall algorithm but it does not seem to do the trick in my case and keeps on running in all eternity. The implementation is tested on some smaller graphs and is correctly implemented. I am using a graphical representation such as (but much larger than):

```
graph = {0: {1: 3, 3:8, 4:5},
         1: {0: 3, 2:5},
         2: {1: 5, 3:4, 4:1 },
         3: {0: 8, 2:4, 4:3},
         4: {0:5, 2:1, 3:3}}
```

Key are vertices, and ultimately the value is the weight. Is there any library that could help me with this task?

Comment: I don't know about a library, but the Floyd-Warshall algorithm is easy to implement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

Comment: I have already tried it. It is too computational heavy to complete the task unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I will surely try dijikstra and get back with an response if it worked or not.

Comment: Dijkstra is O(N^2) to find shortest path from a node to all other nodes. You will have to do that N/2 times to find all the path lengths - i..e still O(N^3). Maybe that's why whoever suggested it deleted their comment.

Comment: @Goodol'George Are weights all positive integers?

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is **O(V^3)** which you have said is too slow already.


Now, Dijkstra's is **O(E log V)** with a binomial heap/priority queue but as you said there are around 3 times more edges than verticies then this is equivalent to **O(V log V)** (this would not be the case if there was say an edge between most 2 nodes).

This means that if you run Dijkstras from every node you will get **O(V^2 log V)** which is a significantly slower growth rate then  **O(N^3)**

Comment: @themiurge yes they are. I.e. all distances > 0.

Comment: @MarcusHandley, I see that is unfortunate. Do you have any idea of how to solve this? Would a fast computer (without clustering) be able to compute this in some 10 minutes or so?

Comment: Being all weights positive integers, you could take a look at Thorup's algorithm (see [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=316548) for reference). I found a Java implementation [here](https://github.com/npruehs/thorup). It's O(E+V) for a single vertex, thus O(V^2) in your case. Worth a try.

Comment: If weights are small integers bound by a constant value you can also use a specialized variant of Dijkstra's algorithm (see the [relevant section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Specialized_variants) on Wikipedia).

Comment: @themiurge Thank you very much! The regular Dijkstra was much faster than Floyd Warshall in my case, it calculated all lengths in around 4 minutes. The distances are floats of values between 1 - 2. I will surely check out both Thorups and the specialized variant of Dijkstra if they could improve performance.

Comment: @Goodol'George I should have clarified. Its having a significantly slower growth rate means that your algorithm with be faster i.e; the time till completion will grow less quickly. My calculations suggested that this should be able to run in a few seconds, but this is dependent on your processor and your language(probably not applicable for python). However themiurge's is **O(V^2)** which grows slower(and therefore faster) by a factor of **O(log V)**. Did their solution work?

Comment: @MarcusHandley I haven't tried the other ones themiurge suggested yet. The dijkstra is applicable for the problem I am trying to solve at the moment. I will surely try them if I have to speed things up a little bit more in the future. Thanks for your great and helpful answere!